# Redirect website to WWW apache .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I want to redirect kwikku.com to www.kwikku.com

What should I add in my `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.in
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```